# Changing a for-loop into a recursive function

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion

so I've read that you can turn any loop into a recursive function, and I was wondering how I might be able to turn the code below (prints out the permutations of a string) into one (replacing the for loop with a recursive function). I'm not asking for a solution, but rather the way of thinking to approach such a task. Thanks!

```
private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {

 int n = str.length();

  if (n == 0) System.out.println(prefix);

  else {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
  }
}
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: That is recursive.... You should be reading up on what recursion actually means.

Comment: You're already using recursion in the example above. Here's more on it: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/

Comment: Even though you have a for loop inside the method, you're still performing recursion by calling the function within itself.

Comment: In response to your edit, see my original comment, it is still valid. You clearly don't even know what that code is supposed to be doing

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the contract you do it by making a helper.

```java
private static void permutationFor(int i, int n, String prefix, String str) {
    if( i < n ) {
        permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), 
                    str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
        permutationFor(i+1, n, prefix, str);
    }
}
```

Thus you change the for loop with a call to `permututaionFor`

```java
private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        premutationFor(0, n, prefix, str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters to represent the lower and upper bounds,

```
private static void permutation(String prefix, String str, int i, int j) {
```

add a boundary condition at the beginning of permutation,

```
if(i < j){
```

then omit the `for` loop, and in your already-recursive call to permutation,

```
permutation(..., i+1, j);
```

and finally, when you call it initially from your other code, pass 0 and the parameter str's .length() as the values of i and j.

You could also create another permutation(...) overload that takes the two extra parameters, so your initial call doesn't have to figure them out.

Note that you can remove some of the redundancy around `n` in your code, but you can get this working without doing so.